# Présent ou plus-que-parfait ?

Tags: usage, temps-grammatical, style-de-rédaction

Durant un jeu en ligne, j'ai reçu ce message :

> Vous avez été déconnecté de [le jeu] car vous êtes inactif depuis un moment...

Devrait-ce être ?

> Vous avez été déconnecté de [le jeu] car vous aviez été inactif depuis un moment...

Ou l'imparfait ?

> ... vous étiez inactif...

Comment: Si vous avez lu quelque part que l'imparfait et le plus que parfait sont utilisés pour « les actions qui durent » (fort probable, car ça apparait par exemple sur ce forum sur presque toute question sur l'imparfait), il est temps de comprendre que c'est faux.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais lu ça.

Comment: Les temps utilisés dans ce message semblent correspondre au moment où il est envoyé, et non au moment où vous le lirez. Au moment de la déconnection, vous êtes considéré comme actuellement inactif(ve), d'où le présent simple. Par contre, l'action de déconnecter votre compte est finie, d'où l'usage du passé composé au début du message.

Answer (score 2):

Le présent est correct mais, j'utiliserais aussi le passé composé :

> Vous avez été déconnecté de [le jeu] car vous avez été inactif depuis un moment...

mais certainement pas le plus-que-parfait.

Comment: Pas d'accord : ici le passé composé ne colle pas avec *depuis* (qui va bien avec le présent au contraire). On aurait pu dire *vous avez été inactif pendant un moment*.

Answer (score 1):

Le plus-que-parfait me paraît incorrect. L'imparfait est nettement plus élégant.